# Can you tell the sign of second derivative of 2-variable function when signs of first derivatives known?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a function

$$g(x,y)$$

where I know the signs of the first partial derivatives:
$$ \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}>0 \quad \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}<0$$

Is this sufficient info to know the sign of
$$ \frac{\partial^2 g(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}?$$

Comment: Have you tried forming several examples and seeing if two of them can give different signs?

Comment: You could answer this yourself for the one variable function $f(x)$ does $f'(x)$ say anything about $f''(x)$  does knowing $f(x)>0 $say anything about $ f'(x)$

Comment: Thanks for the reply; the answer to your question is obviously that it doesn't, but can you really translate that to the example I gave here?

Comment: @MrQ Please check out what I have added to my answer below, which gets around the problem of where the partials are evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=-x^3y^3$ and evaluate partials at $(1,-1)$ [denote partials by substripts].
Then $A_x=-3x^2y^3$ is positive at $(1,-1),$ $A_y=-3x^3y^2$ is negative at $(1,-1),$ and finally $a_{xy}=-9x^2y^2$ is negative at $(1,-1).$

On the other hand, let $B=-A$ and evaluate the partials at $(-1,1).$ Then $B_x>0,\ B_y<0,$ but this time $B_{xy}=+9x^2y^2$ is positive at $(-1,1).$

Note I evaluated partials for the two functions at two different points. I dont know whether such examples can be made if one requires all evaluations to be at the same point.

**Added later:** I have now found two functions for which each satisfies that the first partial wrt $x$ is positive, and the first partial wrt $y$ is negative, and for the two functions the mixed partial wrt $x,y$ has differing signs. In addition, both functions are differentiable on  the whole plane, an this sign behavior holds for *every* point $(x,y)$ in the plane *other than the origin.*

The functions are: $f(x,y)=e^{x^3-y^3}$ and $g(x,y)=-e^{y^3-x^3}.$

Details for for the $f$ function: $f_x=3x^2e^{x^3-y^3},$ and $f_y=-3y^2e^{x^3-y^3}.$ For the mixed partial of $f$ we have $f_{xy}=-9x^2y^2e^{x^3-y^3}.$

Details for the $g$ function: $g_x=3x^2e^{y^3-x^3},$ and $g_y=-3y^2e^{y^3-x^3}.$ For the mixed partial of $g$ we have $g_{xy}=+9x^2y^2e^{y^3-x^3}.$

I believe this new example shows without a doubt that the sign of the mixed partial cannot be determined just knowing the partial wrt $x$ is positive and the partial wrt $y$ is negative. Because this is one example where the mixed partials have different signs no matter at what non-origin point in the plane the partials are evaluated at.

**Final point:** I said above that the sign behavior is as desired at every nonorigin point, but now realize one needs to restrict to the set of points $(x,y)$ for which neither of $x,y$ are zero, ie. the "non-axis" points.

Just realized I can redefine the two examples as $f(x,y)=e^{x-y},\ g(x,y)=-e^{y-x},$ and then no need to eliminate *any* pairs $(x,y)$ to get the claimed sign behavior. Don't know if that really matters but it fixes the one drawback I saw.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MrQ Glad to help. I found the question quite interesting, will upvote it now.